# how to set default group for new user in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

how can I set default group for new users that I create?
I didn't create custom model of user and My django version is 1.11.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are not using custom user models, or proxy models, one possible option is to use signals, so whenever a user is created, you can assign the corresponding group:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='group_name'))
```

Comment: I tested, but it didn't set the group.

Comment: This worked for me:   `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='group_name'))`

Comment: Oh!! of course!! Silly me, I forgot that group was a many to many field, and I posted my answer from memory. Sorry! Glad you figured it out, I will update the question for next users. Mark it as accepted if you wish to help more people!

Comment: Also note that this many to many relationship needs an Id so you can't override save method even if you code a custom user model.